# How to make a default template type?

Tags: c++

I've searched with the line of the title here and found nothing, but I'm pretty sure there's a way to make a default type for templates with empty brackets such as those `<>` instead of something like `<int>` or `<double>` etc...

 So I tried

```
template <class T = char>
```

Which actually compiles but doesn't seem to do anything (or does it?). 

Any ideas or suggestions? Links to sources of info that explain the 'how to' and all are welcome too.

EDIT: example code

Ok, so I've made a small piece of code to add, surprisingly though it compiles just fine and does exactly what it's meant to:

Header.hpp:

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T = char>
class test{
private:
  T type;
public:
  test(T type){ this->type = type;}
  T get_type(){ return type;}
};

.cpp:
#include "Header.hpp"
int main(){
test<> t1('t');
cout << t1.get_type() << endl; //prints: t
return 0;
}
```

soo... I guess I'll just need to work harder on finding the problem in the bigger code, it feels inappropriate to post the bigger code here, so... (should I delete this post?).

Comment: Please post your full code, because that seems ok to me.

Comment: welp, the full code is quite large but I can make something in 5-10 mins. In short though, when I try to initialize a class object with empty type-brackets <> it won't compile, do I need to make a constructor for that perhaps?

Comment: Works here: http://ideone.com/3Dol45

Comment: I meant a full mock-up code, that shows the problem you are having and we can compile it.

Comment: your code is correct as an example of default template parameter, see here for a similar example with some explanation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bys786s7.aspx